# Replacing nested map array calls with a single filter method

Tags: javascript

Given the following object:

```
let data = { id: 1,
             pets: [
               {
                name: "",
                myPets: [ 
                  { 
                    name: ""
                    breed: ""
                  },
                  { 
                    name: "Jack"
                    breed: "poodle"
                  }

                ]
             ]
           }
```

Looking for a cleaner way of writing the following to check for at least one record that has a pet name assigned within the myPets array.

I've used two nested `.maps` but not sure if I can accomplish the below with a `.filter` as unsure how to approach this, using `.filter`?

```
data.pets.map((pet) => {
  if (pet.myPets.length > 0) {
    pet.myPets.map((myPet) => {
      if (myPet.name) {
        console.log("Pet name found");
      } else {
        console.log("Pet name not found");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you want as the output ? An array of Pets ? An array of myPets ?

Answer (score 0):

A single `.filter` call won't do the trick unless you preprocess the data you operate on into a flat array. While this is technically possible, it makes no sense - especially as you would employ some iteration method thus defeating the goal of using a single `.filter` only.

Either keep your code or change it into a sequence of filters and mappings as in the `search` function below:

- First filter: Only records with non-empty `myPets` pass
- The mapping extracts `myPets` from each record, the property of interest
- Second filter: Drops arrays that have no records with non-empty `.name` property, by means of the `some` method.

The result of calling the function `search` that encapsulates this procedure is the array of `myPets` properties that meet the filter criteria.

You might want to have the `pets` property instead, drop the mapping step and replace `candidate.some` with `candidate.some.myPets`.

If your actual `data` is an array of records, wrap the code in another `.filter` - see the second code snippet for the specific coding.

Whether or not this coding style is 'cleaner' might be open to discussion. The naming of the array methods suggest what is happening in each stage, thus making the code easier to understand, as does the uniform structure of the 'processing pipeline' and operating on the part of the data that is of interest in each step.

```
    function search ( data, note ) {
        let found = 
               data.pets
                   .filter ( pet => {
                         return (pet.myPets.length > 0); 
                      })
                   .map ( pet => { return pet.myPets; } )
                   .filter ( candidate => {
                         return candidate.some ( thatpet => {
                             if (thatpet.name) {
                                console.log ( `Pet name '${thatpet.name}' found, there may be more (${note}).` );
                             }
                             return thatpet.name;
                         });
                    })
            ;

        if (found.length === 0) { console.log(`Pet name not found (${note})`); }
    } // search
```

Solution test, comparing with the original version ( some syntax errors corrected ).

```js
let data0 = { id: 1,
         pets: [
           {
              name: ""
            , myPets: [ 
                { 
                    name: ""
                  , breed: ""
                },
                { 
                    name: ""
                  , breed: ""
                }
              ]
           }
         ]
       }
, data1 = { id: 1,
         pets: [
           {
              name: ""
            , myPets: [ 
                { 
                    name: ""
                  , breed: ""
                },
                { 
                    name: "Jack"
                  , breed: "poodle"
                }
              ]
           }
         ]
       }
, data2 = { id: 1,
         pets: [
           {
              name: ""
            , myPets: [ 
                { 
                    name: "Fluffy"
                  , breed: "Retriever"
                },
                { 
                    name: "Jack"
                  , breed: "poodle"
                }
              ]
           }
         ]
       }
;

console.log('>>> Original >>>');
data1.pets.map((pet) => {
  if (pet.myPets.length > 0) {
    pet.myPets.map((myPet) => {
      if (myPet.name) {
        console.log("Pet name found");
      } else {
        console.log("Pet name not found");
      }
    });
  }
});
console.log('<<< Original <<<');
console.log('\n');
console.log('>>> Revised >>>');


function search ( data, note ) {
    let found = 
           data.pets
               .filter ( pet => {
                     return (pet.myPets.length > 0); 
                  })
               .map ( pet => { return pet.myPets; } )
               .filter ( candidate => {
                     return candidate.some ( thatpet => {
                         if (thatpet.name) {
                            console.log ( `Pet name '${thatpet.name}' found, there may be more (${note}).` );
                         }
                         return thatpet.name;
                     });
                })
        ;

    if (found.length === 0) { console.log(`Pet name not found (${note})`); }
} // search

[
    data0
  , data1
  , data2
].forEach ( (d, idx) => {search (d, `run #${idx}`);} );

console.log('<<< Revised <<<');
```

**Alternate version**

Modified solution to process recordsets.

```js
   let data = [
        {
            id: 1
          , pets: [
               {
                  name: ""
                , myPets: [ 
                    { 
                        name: ""
                      , breed: ""
                    },
                    { 
                        name: ""
                      , breed: ""
                    }
                  ]
               }
            ]
        }
      , {
            id: 2
          , pets: [
               {
                  name: ""
                , myPets: [ 
                    { 
                        name: "Chuck"
                      , breed: "pug"
                    },
                    { 
                        name: ""
                      , breed: ""
                    }
                  ]
               }
            ]
        }
      , {
            id: 3
          , pets: [
               {
                  name: ""
                , myPets: [ 
                    { 
                        name: "Chuck"
                      , breed: "pug"
                    },
                    { 
                        name: ""
                      , breed: ""
                    }
                  ]
               }
            ]
        }
    ]
  ;
  
  let filtered_resultset =
        data.filter ( rec => {
             let toPass =
                (rec.pets
                    .filter ( pet => {
                        return (pet.myPets.length > 0); 
                     })
                    .map ( pet => { return pet.myPets; } )
                    .filter ( candidate => {
                         return candidate.some ( thatpet => {
                             return thatpet.name;
                         });
                     })
                        .length > 0)
               ;
               
             return toPass;
        })
    ;
 
  console.log(`Filtered Resultset (ids only): ${JSON.stringify(filtered_resultset.map( rec => rec.id))}`);
```